# SAP GUI - vba code to handle error/warning messages

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I'm trying to make a script working for the creation of sales orders.
During the creation there are some informative or warning pop-ups and I would like to code it based on the message type of the pop-up.

I somehow cannot make it work based on .MessageType but when I use .Text and the actual name of the pop-up it works. As different people will use it, I would like to make it independent of the system language.

The current code is as follows and I've added my remarks throughout:

```
SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]").Maximize
SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nva01"
SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBAK-AUART").Text = "ABC"
SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBAK-VKORG").Text = "1234"
SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBAK-VKGRP").SetFocus
SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBAK-VKGRP").caretPosition = 3
SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
SAP_session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsMYTABSTRIP/tabpRAUF").Select
SAP_session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsMYTABSTRIP/tabpRAUF/ssubSUB1:SAPLV45C:0301/ctxtLV45C-VBELN").Text = SAP_example
SAP_session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsMYTABSTRIP/tabpRAUF/ssubSUB1:SAPLV45C:0301/ctxtLV45C-KETDAT").Text = SAP_Date
SAP_session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsMYTABSTRIP/tabpRAUF/ssubSUB1:SAPLV45C:0301/ctxtLV45C-KETDAT").SetFocus
SAP_session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsMYTABSTRIP/tabpRAUF/ssubSUB1:SAPLV45C:0301/ctxtLV45C-KETDAT").caretPosition = 10
SAP_session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[5]").press

If SAP_session.findById("wnd[2]/sbar").MessageType = "W" Then 'I cannot make this work
    SAP_session.findById("wnd[2]").sendVKey 0
End If

'If SAP_session.findById("wnd[2]").Text = "Warning" Then 'this works though
'SAP_session.findById("wnd[2]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
'End If

Do While SAP_session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar").MessageType = "I" 'I tried to make a loop for informative messages as there may be multiple pop-ups but it only works with .Text as above
        SAP_session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 0
        If SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]").Text = "Availability check" Then
        SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[18]").press
            Exit Do
        End If
Loop

SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUBSCREEN_HEADER:SAPMV45A:4021/txtVBKD-BSTKD").Text = POCustomer
SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4401/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4900/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_AUFTRAG/txtRV45A-KWMENG[3,0]").Text = Volume
SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4401/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4900/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_AUFTRAG/txtKOMV-KBETR[16,0]").Text = Price
SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4401/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4900/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_AUFTRAG/txtKOMV-KBETR[16,0]").SetFocus
SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4401/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4900/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_AUFTRAG/txtKOMV-KBETR[16,0]").caretPosition = 16
SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0

Do While SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/sbar").MessageType = "W" 'a lot of warning messages where this code doesn't work
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
Loop

SAP_session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/btnSPOP-VAROPTION1").press
SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUBSCREEN_HEADER:SAPMV45A:4021/btnBT_HEAD").press

SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\03").Select
SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\03/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4303/ctxtVBKD-ZTERM").Text = Payment_term
SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\03/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4303/ctxtVBKD-ZTERM").SetFocus
SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\03/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4303/ctxtVBKD-ZTERM").caretPosition = 4
SAP_session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 0
SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").press
SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press
SAP_session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press

Cells(2, 24).Value = Mid(SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/sbar").Text, 18, 10) 'is it possible to extract the numbers only? Because this is a workaround but depending on the system language it might not work

Exit Sub
```

As this is the first time that I'm trying to create a code, I was hoping that someone would be able to help me out.

Comment: Looking at the documentation, 'MessageType' isn't a property of GuiContainer, might it have a different name or be in a sub-element of the result? `SAP_session.findById(ex).something.MessageType`

Comment: Good question, I don't know. 

Is it also possible to check each pop-up throughout the script if the text says "Information" and just to enter it. 

Everything I tried, I need to create a new if statement on each step where it might show up but I want to include every possibility